# How can we add js using discord.js using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

In the

`message.channel.send(output, {code: "js"});`

code it always says

`Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.`

what the {code: "js"} do is that it adds `````` to the code how do i fix this?

keep in mind I am using WOKCommand handler.

```js
import { ICommand } from "wokcommands";
import { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } from "discord.js";
import { inspect } from "util"

export default {
    category: 'Moderation',
    description: 'Deletes multiple messages at once.',

    ownerOnly: true,

    maxArgs: 1,
    expectedArgs: '[amount]',

    slash: false,

    callback: async ({client, message, args}) => {
        if (message.author.id !== '763857069413367878') return;

        const code = args.join(" ");
        if(!code) return `Please provide some code to evaluate`

        try {
            const result = await eval(code);
            let output = result;
            if(typeof result !== 'string') {
                output = inspect(result)
            }
            message.channel.send(output, {code: "js"});
        } catch (error) {
            message.channel.send('Evaluated some code but to long!')
        };
    },
} as ICommand
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? It says the `send` method expects 1 argument and you are passing it 2 arguments: `output` and `{code: "JS"}`.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of discord.js you now need to pass everything in one object.

This can be done like this:

```
message.channel.send({content: output, code: "js"});
```

Comment: I am now getting;
 `Argument of type '{ content: any; code: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | MessagePayload | MessageOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'code' does not exist in type 'MessagePayload | MessageOptions'.` Error.

Comment: Never mind i fixed it